# Can I rescale or resize a 3D model that was created from a set of images?

Tags: 3d, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, blender, meshroom

I have created a 3D model from a set of images using the Alice-Vision Meshroom, but I want to know if I can resize this model using Blender or any other program.

I want to resize it to be the size of another image or to another object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Blender.

File, Import, WavefrontOBJ, find the .obj from the Meshroom file, Meshroom Cache, Texturing, long alphanumeric folder, texturedMesh.obj, and the same .mtl. Select both, click the blue button 'Import Wavefront OBJ'.

This will place the mesh in Blender. Probably a large file size so may take a while to load.
It will come in at an odd rotation, select it, and rotate it about to be upright or however, you want it.

Clean it up in Edit mode as will probably be needed to remove things not part of the item you want like the ground.
Select the object, Press S for scale, move the mouse and click to set.

```
[Import][1]
[Arrived in Blender at odd rotation][2]
[Rotated to be upright][3]
[Scaled, smaller. Default cube as reference size][4]


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFAmv.jpg

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIGR2.jpg

[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeLnq.jpg

[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqrQr.jpg
```